# How android will know towhich provider it must connect if it is already connected to WiFi and after some time WiFi disappeared?

Tags: android, location, maps, location-provider, android-maps-utils

**Code for switching  to best locationproviders in android maps**

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a little bit?
As I understand, you are asking, how does an app (Android Maps) knows when to connect to GPS or?

Comment: How we can switch automatically to other provider in android maps ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

check this and you will get answer.
by using this we can switch provider in regular intervals according to its availability and accuracy. :)